# find the index of all matching search string in a given string and then insert a new word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string, for example:

> In an out of the box way to reduce number of cigarette consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer cigarettes. Cigarettes have a bad influence on health

Have to find the occurrence of cigarette and insert a `<span style='color: red;'>` before it to highlight?

```
string search = "cigaret";
string lbltxt = Label1.Text;

int startIndex = Label1.Text.IndexOf(search,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
int endIndex = Label1.Text.IndexOf(search,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) +  (search.Length);
Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Insert(endIndex, "</span>");
Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Insert(findIndex, "<span style='color: red;'>");
```

This bit of code finds only the first occurrence and highlights it only once in the original string instead of thrice.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JQUERY

```
   $("p").html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\b(cigarette)\b/g, '<strong class="test">$1</strong>');
});
```

and a css

```
   .test {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Go through this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/EGtBy/218/

I think this would be easy and safe way of working.

And you can use same for your case sensitive word. I think you can manage now.. Or need any help,then comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) if you really need to do that "ugly replacement"(I think it's a bad practice to add styles that way):

```
string search = "cigarette";
string replacement = "<span style='color: red;'>cigarette</span>";
string sentence = "In an out of the box way to reduce number of cigarette consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer cigarettes. Cigarettes have a bad influence on health";
string newStr = sentence.Replace(search,replacement);
```

Comment: I cannot do replace as search string can be case sensitive. for ex Cigarette may get replaced with cigarette

Comment: Replace is case sensitive. If your dealing with Html, you may need to `Html.Encode` your string back. Anyway doing that to add a style is bad..and if I would have needed a fast workaround I'd go for a `JQuery.css` one.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I would do something like this. Not sure how it will affect the formatting (unless the formatting's HTML).</strike>

```
        StringBuilder final = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string split in Label1.Text.Split(' '))
        {
            if (Regex.Match(split, "[a-zA-Z]+").Value.Equals("cigarettes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                final.Append(@"<span style='color: red;'>");
                final.Append(split);
                final.Append(@"</span>");
            }
            else
            {
                final.Append(split);
            }
            final.Append(' ');
        }
        Label1.Text = final.ToString().Trim();
```

result:

```
In an out of the box way to reduce number of cigarette consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer <span style='color: red;'>cigarettes.</span> <span style='color: red;'>Cigarettes</span> have a bad influence on health
```

Update:

Sorry, you don't have to do Regex. I found out that you can that CultureInfo has a CompareInfo property that can act like an ignore case Contains() method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string yourstring = @"In an out of the box way to reduce number of cigarette consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer cigarettes. Cigarettes have a bad influence on health";
        StringBuilder final = new StringBuilder();
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        foreach (string split in yourstring.Split(' '))
        {
            if (culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(split,"cigarette",CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)!=-1)
            {
                final.Append(@"<span style='color: red;'>");
                final.Append(split);
                final.Append(@"</span>");
            }
            else
            {
                final.Append(split);
            }
            final.Append(' ');
        }
Label1.Text = final.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

Result:

```
In an out of the box way to reduce number of <span style='color: red;'>cigarette</span> consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer <span style='color: red;'>cigarettes.</span> <span style='color: red;'>Cigarettes</span> have a bad influence on health
```

> Thanks for trying. only problem with this solution is, it also
>   highlights the letters which are not in the search string. SInce I
>   have a solution with index for time being will go wth that.

So apparently this is what you want:

```
Label1.Text = Regex.Replace(Label1.Text, @"(cigarette)", @"<span style='color: red;'>$1</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

output is:

```
In an out of the box way to reduce number of <span style='color: red;'>cigarette</span> consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer <span style='color: red;'>cigarette</span>s. <span style='color: red;'>Cigarette</span>s have a bad influence on health
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I like a small tweak in the code. This gives me exact match. where in I like to highlight all the three words cigarette present in the string. Output shld be 
In an out of the box way to reduce number of <span style='color: red;'>cigarette</span> consumption per day, Vineet, a Delhi University student has started smoking longer <span style='color: red;'>cigarettes.</span> <span style='color: red;'>Cigarettes</span> have a bad influence on health

Comment: Thanks for trying. only problem with this solution is, it also highlights the letters which are not in the search string. SInce I have a solution with index for time being will go wth that.

Comment: Aye yi yi. I didn't know that's what you wanted. That's A LOT easier. There's no need for you to write more than a line of code for that, actually. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you're missing the point. I was using the same piece of code initially. Y i wanted the other way is replacing original string with search string is case sensitive. Its a major concern. As others suggested the current solution which I have is no better as I'm including style in the code and it breaks when searched for a single character :) Couldn't believe there is no inbuilt or an extension in string or regex to achieve what I needed..  um.. my head hurts.

Comment: I don't get it. My code contains "RegexOptions.IgnoreCase". It is not case sensitive. Isn't the output what you wanted?

Comment: It won't matter either if you search for a single character with this Regex, and unlike your code operating on so many immutable strings, this one uses the same TextBox property to get and set the string. You will have to escape characters that will conflict with your regex however, but I suggest cross the bridge when you get there (look at this later on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the word like this:

```
string search = "cigaret";
Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Replace(search, "<span style='color: red;'>" + search + "</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally here is a working code, but am sure there might be a much better way to do it. If anyone can improvise it, much appreciated.

```
    string msg = Label1.Text;

    string search = "cigarette";
    int searchStringLength  = search.Length;

    string startTag = "<span style='color: red;'>";
    string endTag = "</span>";
    int skip = startTag.Length + endTag.Length;

    int msgindex = 0;


    do
    {
        msgindex = msg.IndexOf(search, msgindex, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (msgindex == -1) break;

        msg= msg.Insert((msgindex + searchStringLength), endTag);
        msg = msg.Insert(msgindex, startTag);


        msgindex += searchStringLength + skip;

    } while (msgindex != -1);

    Label1.Text = msg;
```

Comment: This is the better way of highlighting html text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715480/how-to-search-a-particular-text-within-an-html-text-and-highlight-the-search-str