# How to search a particular text within an HTML Text and highlight the search string with a color

Tags: c#, html, css, regex, search

We have requirement to search through a HTML text and highlight the text with a particular color.

Ex: The html string is

```
<p class="Pa0" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;"><span class="A1"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">Giving this flyer to your class customers</span></span></p>
```

In the above text I am searching for the word "Class". 
It should highlight the text *class* within the text "Giving this flyer to your class customers"
But whereas it is trying to highlight the css element "class" and as a result the original html text is corrupted and not displayed properly.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue on how to search a content within an HTML text and highlight the search without changing the original HTML.

Comment: Without changing the original HTML? Not possible.

Comment: Shouldn't this be possible with some JavaScript? Get the element by id / class and change innerHTML

Comment: The end result should be something like
<p class="Pa0" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;"><span class="A1"><span style="font-size: 10pt;">Giving this flyer to your <span style='color: red;'>class<span> customers</span></span></p>

Comment: @verbose-mode  This can be a dynamic HTML. So I might not be able to search for an id to check the innerHTML

Comment: Post what you're doing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(class)(?=(?:[^><]*<[^<>]*>)*[^><]*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `<span style='color: red;'>$1<span>`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bB8jY7/3

Comment: Great!!! This is what I was looking for.
Let me try this. Hope I can achieve the desired functionality with this one.

Comment: I would love to mark this as answered as this is so close to the requirement.
However there is one thing which I found strange in using the replace function.
In the URL I tried as below
regular expression is Class(?=(?:[^><]*<[^<>]*>)*[^><]*$)
identifier is i(Case insensitive)
Test string is <p><span class="A1">Giving this flyer to your CLASS customers</span></p>
Resultant string is <p><span class="A1">Giving this flyer to your <span style='color: red;'>class<span> customers</span></p>
In the resultant string the original case of the string (which is UPPER) has been changed (to lower).

Comment: How can we retain that??? If we don't then the original string will be altered after a search is performed, which is like a bug for QA :(

Comment: You Rock Buddy!!!!
I am sorry that I am unable to vote for this. But I have marked this as answered...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with javascript:

```
var str = document.getElementByClassName("Pa0")[0].children[0].children[0];
str.innerHTML = str.innerHTML.replace(' class ', ' <span style="color:red">class</span> ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think I should elaborate the question a bit.
The user will be able to enter any kind of HTML text. Whatever I have given is just for Example and real situation is like there is an html text and in that without highlighting the html elements like "class" or "style" I need to highlight the original content with in that.

Comment: @NaveenMaverick But you provided example in comments. It isn't what you want?

Comment: Yes, But as I told there is no rule that the html is of the same type in the example. It can contain any tags or class. What I am looking for is a general solution to search some string within any HTML text and highlight the string within the html string with some color.

Comment: @Nav but this is general solution!